# Icon not showing in QListWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidgetitem, qicon

Icons are not showing in my `QListWidgetItem`s.

**Edit 2:**

Turns out you can't use absoulte path. You must use relative path. But why is this the case?

---

Minimum reproducible example:

```
import json
import os
import sys
from math import floor

from PyQt5 import QtTest, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtDesigner import QFormBuilder
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QGridLayout, QLabel, QMainWindow, QScrollArea, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, \
    QListView, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QToolButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint, Qt, QIODevice, QFile
from PyQt5.Qt import QPixmap

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)



        #ListWidget
        listWidget = QListWidget(self)
        listWidget.setViewMode(QListWidget.IconMode)
        listWidget.setFixedSize(500, 700)

        dir = r'Players'
        for filename in os.listdir(dir):

            #Item
            item = QListWidgetItem(QIcon('Players/Pogba.jpg'), '<Name>', listWidget)



if __name__ == "__main__":



    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.showMaximized()
    app.exec_()
```

I followed the docs(https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html), so why are they not appearing?

**Edit:**

It looks like it only happens when the image is outside the source code's folder. Why is this the case?

Comment: 1) please provide a [mre], 2) I see that "Snippet" and ·"Full code" have the same lines of code, is it an error?